# Workflow rule criteria

Tags: workflow

We have a workflow rule which fires based on the status field i.e. if it is closed, then it sends emails to end users as they are termed as the receipients from one of the lookup field of the user (Related user).

We often have data migration or update on this object and due to this unnecessarily the mails are triggered to the users(Please note the status of those records are already closed).How can we stop it to fire the mails to the users even though as per business design it is fine if they can close the status field, mail should go?(We are not considering to deactivate the workflow rule as it will affect and mails will not be triggered)

Please remember for migration, we use a special profile. So, can it be bypassed in rule criteria like current user profile not equal to migration profile, so that mails will not trigger unnecessarily and simultaneously actual mail will go when end user changes the status to closed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes in workflow rule criteria. set the condition that `$user.ProfileId != 'YourMigrationUserProfile'`. SO that it will not run for the same profile.

Comment: @Sau2403 if this solved your problem then you can close this question

Answer (score 0):

You can change the criteria on WF that it get's triggered only when `Status` value is set to "Closed":

`AND(
 ISCHANGED(Status__c),
 ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Closed")
)`

Or when you don't plan to use any time dependant actions, you can set **Evaluation Criteria** to ***Evaluate the rule when a record is:***

- created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

and have **Rule Criteria** as `Status__c equals "Closed"`